# Ao fazer o upload, o nome do arquivo virar o título

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Colegas.

É possível o usuário ao fazer o upload de um arquivo, o nome do arquivo virar o título da página? Por exemplo:

O usuário irá preencher um formulário onde o primeiro campo é o upload de arquivo e o segundo campo é um input text. Quando ele selecionar o arquivo pelo upload "materia_matematica.pdf", preencher automaticamente o input text  "Matéria Matemática".

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
$('#file').on('change', function() {
  var f_name = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
  $('#name_file').val(f_name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="text" id="name_file">
```

E para mudares o titulo da página dinamicamente podes fazer:

```
$('#file').on('change', function() {
  var f_name = $(this)[0].files[0].name;;
  document.title = f_name;
});
```

Comment: Perfeito Miguel, muito bom. Só mais uma coisa, como faria para tirar a extensão do título?

Comment: @Fox.11, vou acrescentar, é que não percebi se querias o input ou o titulo

Comment: Obrigado Miguel.

Comment: De nada @Fox.11. Ainda bem que resolveste, desta maneira consegues aceder a várias coisas referentes ao ficheiro, ex: `$(this)[0].files[0].type;` que dá `"image/jpeg"` e a outros quantos dados

Answer (score 2):

Com javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="arquivo" type="file" >

    <script>
        document.getElementById("arquivo").onchange = function(){
            var name = this.value.replace(/.*[\/\\]/, ''); // limpar nome para chrome
             document.title = name.split(".")[0];
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas Costa